# XSLT : recursive string concatenation from parent/child structure

Tags: xslt, recursion, concatenation

I'd like some help on a topic I cannot find a solution to (and I'm a tad on the rush...)
I'm average in XSLT and this point is beyond my skills.

My source XML has got a tree structure organized as Child/Parent, already sorted with top nodes up.

EDITED : added top enclosing for Department nodes.
Here's an example :

```
<AllDepartments>
 <Department>
  <Code>1</Code>
  <ParentCode></ParentCode>
  <Label>IT</Label>
 </Department>
 <Department>
  <Code>2</Code>
  <ParentCode>1</ParentCode>
  <Label>Security</Label>
 </Department>
 <Department>
  <Code>3</Code>
  <ParentCode>2</ParentCode>
  <Label>SSO</Label>
 </Department>
</AllDepartments>
```

I'd like the output to be formatted as :

```
<AllDepartments>
 <Department>
    <Code>1</Code>
    <ParentCode></ParentCode>
    <Label>IT</Label>
  </Department>
  <Department>
    <Code>2</Code>
    <ParentCode>1</ParentCode>
    <Label>Security</Label>
  </Department>
  <Department>
    <Code>3</Code>
    <ParentCode>1.2</ParentCode>
    <Label>SSO</Label>
  </Department>
</AllDepartments>
```

It means that, as soon as I reach the 3rd level, ParentCode should be a concatenation of all ParentCode ancestors (including ParentCode itself), with a dot as separator.
The maximum depth of level is 7, thus I was looking for a recursive concatenation algorithm.

I've tried some XSL I'm too ashamed to show (trying call-template, apply-template)... 
I've looked for similar topics, found some but not as "simple" as my case.

Any help would be appreciated (XSLT 2.0 allowed).

Comment: Neither your input nor your output are well-formed XML documents!

Comment: I'm sorry, the enclosing elements were lost in a lousy copy-paste.
The list of "Department" nodes is enclosed in 2 levels of nodes.
I'll edit my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you will need a **well-formed** XML input, with a single root element such as:

**XML**

```
<Departments>
   <Department>
      <Code>1</Code>
      <ParentCode/>
      <Label>IT</Label>
   </Department>
   <Department>
      <Code>2</Code>
      <ParentCode>1</ParentCode>
      <Label>Security</Label>
   </Department>
   <Department>
      <Code>3</Code>
      <ParentCode>2</ParentCode>
      <Label>SSO</Label>
   </Department>
</Departments>
```

Then you can use:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:key name="parent" match="Department" use="Code" />

<xsl:template match="ParentCode">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('parent', .)" mode="parent"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Department" mode="parent">
    <xsl:if test="string(ParentCode)">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('parent', ParentCode)" mode="parent"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="ParentCode"/>
        <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to get:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Departments>
   <Department>
      <Code>1</Code>
      <ParentCode/>
      <Label>IT</Label>
   </Department>
   <Department>
      <Code>2</Code>
      <ParentCode>1</ParentCode>
      <Label>Security</Label>
   </Department>
   <Department>
      <Code>3</Code>
      <ParentCode>1.2</ParentCode>
      <Label>SSO</Label>
   </Department>
</Departments>
```

Comment: Indeed, there are 2 levels of enclosing nodes above the "department" ones.
Anyway, I've tried your solution without success. The code doesn't seem to go through the recursive path.
It means that the first 2 levels are imported, and the 3rd one is not.

The original XML is generated by a proprietary ETL engine, and I've got very few controlling & debugging features. Means that I'm pretty much doing "blindfold" XSL. Only errors msgs @ processing give me little clue about the malformed XSLT...

Comment: You can see my solution working here: http://xsltransform.net/ncntCTq If you are getting a different result, then you must be doing something differently - and I have no way of knowing what.

Comment: Indeed, your solution gives the expected results. I've done many tries on the online testing url.
So, I guess my issues are related to the ETL itself.
Thanks A LOT !